# You won't have much left,you won't have enough for yourself

Tags: word-usage

A person offers a bit food to his friend. So his friend says:

> Sorry I can't have it. Because if I do,you won't have much left.(**/you won't have enough left**).

So what sounds natural? *Option 1 or option2*? And is there a better and more natural alternative?

Comment: I don't think anybody would normally talk about there being food left in the first place. (Nor would they use your first sentence—unless they had some medical condition preventing them from eating the food or were on a diet.) They would simply say, "No, thank you. You have it." But it's not clear if you're asking for that an entire response that's more natural—or if you specifically want a more natural *food left* phrase.

Comment: @Jasom Bassford, I want a more natural "food left" phrase

Comment: I disagree. One does talk about food left: "Oh, is there any salad left?" or any type of food. You might say to someone at a party if the dish has been gobbled up by the partygoers. The only odd thing is: to offer a bit of food to someone. I'd say: to offer some food to someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely subjective.

As I said in a comment under the question, a more natural rephrasing of the *entire* sentence (and its meaning) is simply:

> No, thanks. You can have it.

Most people would not go on (unprompted) to say that they don't want something because, if they did, that would result in there not being enough for somebody else.

---

But if the focus really is on *only* the specific *food left* phrases, both of your suggestions sound equally natural to me—although I suspect *enough* is more common:

> you won't have enough left
>   you won't have much left

In the right context, there might be a minimum amount of something that's required in order for something else to happen. If that's the case, then *enough* would need to be used rather than *much*.

Also, when used in a question form, the following would be true:

> ✔ Are you sure you have enough?
>   ✘ Are you sure you have much?

Simply because of the parallel structure between question and statement, the statement using *enough* is likely more common—but I can't say that with certainty.

If I were to choose one or the other of the statements (not questions), I would choose the *enough* version. But I find nothing wrong with the *much* version either.

---

In terms of general phrasing, and using either of those specific words, if *I* were to write that entire part, I would write it differently:

> there won't be enough left for you
>   there won't be much left for you

---

Further, if I were to rewrite the entire conversation, I would start off with what I suggested originally, and then finish with my latter suggestion—but with a further change:

> "Would you like some of my food?"
>   "No, thanks. You can have it."
>   "Are you sure?"
>   "Yes, I'm sure. If I had it, there wouldn't be enough left for you."

While there is also nothing wrong with the other verb tenses, I personally prefer the *if I had* and *there wouldn't* version. It's simply more natural to my own way of speaking when it comes to hypothetical situations.

---

As another comment, when I hear *I can't have it*, I assume it means that the person is prohibited from having it, rather than choosing not to have it. For instance, in the case of food, perhaps they have an allergy or are on a diet. Which is why I changed *I can't have it* to *you can have it*.

Answer (score 0):

A person offers a bit food to his friend. So his friend says:

Sorry I can't have it. Because if I do,you won't have much left.(/you won't have enough left).

**Generally,** when refusing food that has been offered in this context, one would say:

**Sorry, I can't take it.**
**Sorry, I can't accept it.**
**Sorry, I simply cannot accept it.**
**Sorry, I won't accept it.**

Because if I do, **there won't be much left for you.**

Generally, here, one says: there won't be etc.

Answer (score -1):

Your sentences are correct. I think the one below is a little more usual.

> Thank you, but I will not accept. There won't be enough for you if I did.

Comment: can I say "there *wouldn't* be enough ... if "?

Comment: It is correct grammatically. But the meaning is slightly different. If you use "wouldn't", it implies that you are not sure about the result. If you use "won't", then it is sure that the quantity left is not enough.